What role does "following" play in its sentence?

Russian forces launched offensive operations intended to seize Pokrovsk in Donetsk Oblast during Spring 2024 at the moment of greatest constraints on Ukraine's manpower and materiel following the suspension of US assistance in Fall 2023. Russian forces have not taken Pokrovsk after eight months of grinding but consistent advances in western Donetsk Oblast.

Source: https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/ukrainian-defense-pokrovsk-has-compelled-russia-change-its-approach-eastern-ukraine


Is "following" a verb or preposition?
What exactly does "following the suspension of US assistance in Fall 2023" modify?
Could "the moment of greatest constraints on Ukraine's manpower and materiel following the suspension of US assistance in Fall 2023" be replaced with "the moment of greatest constraints on Ukraine's manpower and materiel that was subsequent to the suspension of US assistance in Fall 2023"?


OP has enquired about the role of "following" in the sentence:

Russian forces launched offensive operations intended to seize Pokrovsk in Donetsk Oblast during Spring 2024 at the moment of greatest constraints on Ukraine's manpower and materiel following the suspension of US assistance in Fall 2023.

Answering each question one by one:

I.What role does "following" play in its sentence? Is "following" a verb or preposition?

"Following" functions as a preposition (meaning after) in this sentence (Cambridge dictionary link) . It introduces the prepositional phrase  "following the suspension of US assistance in Fall 2023," which establishes a temporal relationship  between the "suspension of assistance" and "the constraints on Ukraine's manpower and materiel".

following.
preposition.
after:
The weeks following the riots were extremely tense.


II. What exactly does "following the suspension of US assistance in Fall 2023" modify?

The prepositional phrase "following the suspension of US assistance in Fall 2023" modifies  "the moment of greatest constraints on Ukraine's manpower and materiel."
This phrase is  "adjectival" in function because it describes the noun "moment, specifying which moment is being referred to.

III. Could "the moment of greatest constraints on Ukraine's manpower and materiel following the suspension of US assistance in Fall 2023" be replaced with "the moment of greatest constraints on Ukraine's manpower and materiel that is subsequent to the suspension of US assistance in Fall 2023"?

Yes, using  "that is subsequent to" in place of "following" retains the same meaning. However, this change converts the concise prepositional phrase into a longer relative clause (though it is grammatically correct)

Reference to your edit: Does "following" mean "was subsequent to". Yes it means "after"

I've undone the change.

a preposition
: subsequent to
following the lecture tea was served
following the suspension of US assistance in Fall 2023 =
subsequent to the suspension of US assistance in Fall 2023
It's a time adverbial. When Russian forces launched their operations. It tells us when they launched them.
[Note: "in the fall of 2023" is preferable]

I didn't downvote your answer.

@Englishgood Thanks. Some people will downvote even correct answers. So tiring, really.

Russian forces launched offensive operations intended to seize Pokrovsk in Donetsk Oblast during Spring 2024 [...] following the suspension of US assistance in Fall 2023.
